# G4 server running slow

Tags: networking

I have HP proliant ML 350 servers. We have 8 remote locations where users connect and log on to our server through DYNDNS to access our company ERP's to conduct day to day work. The base of our company ERP's is Oracle for which we have a separate server.Now the problem is day by day the load on the server is increasing and the speed is getting slower and slower and users are facing a lot of issues . So I  am planning to implement Sonic wall VPN. I conducted a demo of sonic wall but it was slower than the current speed of dyndns. The configuration of my server is as follows :-

1. Linux    HP ProLiant 370 Intel Xenon 3.20 GHZ    150 GB   (72 * 2)       3 GB    Suse
2. Omega    HP ProLiant 370 Intel Xenon 3.20 GHZ    300GB (72.8 * 4)    Raid 5  4 GB    Windows Server 2K3 Enterprise Edition
3. Storage Box  HP Storage Works 1400   Intel Xenon 2.00 GHZ    4 TB(1 TB * 4)  Raid 5  2 GB    Windows Server 2K8 Enterprise Edition
4. Domain & Terminal    HP ProLiant 350 Intel Xenon 3.20 GHZ    250 GB(72.8 * 3)    Raid 5  4 GB    Windows Server 2K3 Enterprise Edition

Can some one help me in improving the speed of my network at remote locations and reduce the problems.

Comment: This website is for professional IT personnel seeking help with (mostly) technical issues. You need a consultant who knows what they're doing. Please see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not surprised it's slower via a VPN than DynDNS, they do different jobs, in fact using DynDNS at all for this scenario is very odd indeed.

You don't mention what kind of incoming comms links you have into your company but obviously analysing those will tell you if they're over-saturated and needing to be expanded. More likely than not you will have *some* bandwidth issues but I'd imagine the problems your seeing are from running 4/5+ year old servers full of old data and running on older versions of code.

If you simply replaced your existing servers with newer kit running on newer OS's you'd obviously see a great deal of performance benefit. You could also possibly virtualise at the same time too, making future migrations easier and giving you other options for disaster recovery.

Either way your performance issues will no doubt come down to both your comms links AND your servers.

Comment: Thank You so Much for you reply. But you see i also thought that my bandwith must be an issue. So I upgraded my ADSL LINES to a much higher speed.But i wanna completely restrict my users accessing my server through RDC  and wanna completly bring my oracle applications on their desktops including their outlook.Because all of these are on their server accounts now which they access through access through DYNDNS. They also face regular printer issues as the spooler on the server stops responding cause of the load on the server. Any sugesstions....???